# Zooming iframe content

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I'm struggling to resize iframe **content** (within a fixed-sized iframe). I.e. I want its content to get smaller/bigger as if the browser's zoom was changed. From css experimentation I get the sense it's possible by defining the iframe page size and rescaling it to the fixed window dimensions. But I can't replicate in javascript. Any assistance appreciated.

```js
var w = $(window).width() * .7;
var h = $(window).height() * .7;
$('#myiframe').width(w + 'px').height(h + 'px');

function zoom(x) {
  console.log(w * x, h * x);
  // document.getElementById("myiframe").width(w).height(h);
  // document.getElementById("myiframe").style.transform = 'scale(' + z + ',' + z + ')';
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#iframe_container {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 70vw;
  height: 70vh;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#myiframe {
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 0;
  -ms-transform: scale(0.25);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
  -o-transform: scale(0.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="zoom(1)">- ZOOM OUT</button>
<button type="button" onclick="zoom(-1)">+ ZOOM IN</button>
<br>
<div id="iframe_container">
  <iframe id="myiframe" src="./iframe.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: My final code (HT to Brett) - https://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/zoLq1t5f/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the iframe source is a different domain, you're out of luck. You won't be able to add CSS if that's the case. Search for the issues and reasons if interested.

The best alternative option might be to change the size of the iframe container, the iframe itself, or `scale` the iframe. Here's how the scale the iframe:

```js
var w = $(window).width();
var h = $(window).height();
var scale = 1;

function zoom(x) {
  if (x === -1) {
    scale = scale * 1.1;
    w = w * 0.9;
    h = h * 0.9;
    $("#myiframe").width(w + "px");
    $("#myiframe").height(h + "px")
  } else {
    scale = scale * 0.9;
    w = w * 1.1;
    h = h * 1.1;
    $("#myiframe").width(w + "px");
    $("#myiframe").height(h + "px")
  }

  $('#myiframe').css('transform', `scale(${scale})`);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#iframe_container {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}

#myiframe {
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="zoom(1)">- ZOOM OUT</button>
<button type="button" onclick="zoom(-1)">+ ZOOM IN</button>
<br>
<div id="iframe_container">
  <iframe id="myiframe" src="//api.gdeltproject.org/api/v2/doc/doc?query=christmas&mode=ArtList&maxrecords=15&timespan=24h"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry Brett, this is changing the size of the iframe. I want to keep that static and zoom the size of the contents.

Comment: Unfortunately if the iframe source is on a different domain you won't be able to add any CSS to the iframe contents. So you're limited to altering the elements on your page. You can reverse the effect I did earlier, so now the iframe size is changed.

Comment: I don't think this can be right. I can achieve what I want in css (host, not embed) - e.g. compare https://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/sh08zh8h/ to https://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/j4mmLg32/. So if it's possible in css it must be in js..

Comment: You're only applying CSS to the iframe, not to the iframe contents. This allows you to `scale()` the iframe. I've updated the solution, is that what you're going for?

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to suggest I wanted to change the embedded iframe css! I need the iframe to stay the same size - see css jsfiddle examples. Your example still changes size (unless my browser is refusing to update..).

Comment: Got it. So we'll need to both `scale()` the iframe, while increasing/decreasing it's width/height at the same time. The solution is almost there, but needs some polishing. I believe the issue is in making the `scale` value match the updated height/width

Comment: Ah this is more like it! certainly behaves like my css examples. Thanks Brett this is super helpful.

Comment: There are a few tasks remaining but hopefully it gets you pointed in the right direction. The scale and width will need to be calibrated based on the initial iframe container width I believe.

Comment: Yeah need some tweaks but I can definitely work with this.